# UIBezierPath doesn't work on a some frames

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uibezierpath

I'm trying to run this code using a `UIView` subclass:

```
bgShapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX , y: self.frame.midY), radius:
            100, startAngle: -90.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 270.degreesToRadians, clockwise: true).cgPath
bgShapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
bgShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
bgShapeLayer.lineWidth = 15
self.layer.addSublayer(bgShapeLayer)
```

For some reason, this code works (shows something) when I'm using a 375x667 frame, but doesn't work when I use another frame (for example 120x120 or 74x74). Maybe the shape is out of bounds? But why?

If anyone can identify a problem I'll be really grateful if you'll let me know.

**Answered full code**:

```
    let timeLeftShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let bgShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    var timeLeft: TimeInterval = 3783
    var endTime: Date?
    var timeLabel =  UILabel()
    var timer = Timer()
    let strokeIt = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")

    func drawBgShape() {
        bgShapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX , y: self.frame.midY), radius:
            min(frame.width/2, frame.height/2), startAngle: -90.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 270.degreesToRadians, clockwise: true).cgPath
        bgShapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        bgShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        bgShapeLayer.lineWidth = 15
        self.layer.addSublayer(bgShapeLayer)
    }
    func drawTimeLeftShape() {
        timeLeftShapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX , y: self.frame.midY), radius:
            min(frame.width/2, frame.height/2), startAngle: -90.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 270.degreesToRadians, clockwise: true).cgPath
        timeLeftShapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        timeLeftShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        timeLeftShapeLayer.lineWidth = 15
        self.layer.addSublayer(timeLeftShapeLayer)
    }
    func addTimeLabel() {
        timeLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: self.frame.midX-50 ,y: self.frame.midY-25, width: 100, height: 50))
        timeLabel.textAlignment = .center
        timeLabel.text = timeLeft.time
        self.addSubview(timeLabel)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.94, alpha: 1.0)
        drawBgShape()
        drawTimeLeftShape()
        addTimeLabel()
        // here you define the fromValue, toValue and duration of your animation
        strokeIt.fromValue = 0
        strokeIt.toValue = 1
        strokeIt.duration = 60
        // add the animation to your timeLeftShapeLayer
        timeLeftShapeLayer.add(strokeIt, forKey: nil)
        // define the future end time by adding the timeLeft to now Date()
        endTime = Date().addingTimeInterval(timeLeft)
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func updateTime() {
        if timeLeft > 0 {
            timeLeft = endTime?.timeIntervalSinceNow ?? 0
            timeLabel.text = timeLeft.time
        } else {
            timeLabel.text = "00:00"
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you also change the `radius` when you change the frame? Otherwise you'll have a diameter (twice the radius) that's larger than the frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the radius 100 needs at least a height of 200

so change it to this

```
 let radius = min(frame.width/2, frame.height/2);
```

Edit this works with me

```
    let df = qw()

    df.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)

    self.view.addSubview(df)
```

import UIKit

```
class qw: UIView {


    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code


        self.drawTimeLeftShape()
    }



    let timeLeftShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let bgShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    var timeLeft: TimeInterval = 3783
    var endTime: Date?
    var timeLabel =  UILabel()
    var timer = Timer()
    let strokeIt = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")

    func drawBgShape() {
        bgShapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX , y: self.frame.midY), radius:
            min(frame.width/2, frame.height/2), startAngle: -90.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 270.degreesToRadians, clockwise: true).cgPath
        bgShapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        bgShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        bgShapeLayer.lineWidth = 15
        self.layer.addSublayer(bgShapeLayer)
    }
    func drawTimeLeftShape() {
        timeLeftShapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX , y: self.frame.midY), radius:
            min(frame.width/2, frame.height/2), startAngle: -90.degreesToRadians, endAngle: 270.degreesToRadians, clockwise: true).cgPath
        timeLeftShapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        timeLeftShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        timeLeftShapeLayer.lineWidth = 15
        self.layer.addSublayer(timeLeftShapeLayer)
    }




}
```

A Demo is here [CircleView](https://github.com/ShKhan9/CircleView)

[image]

Comment: Still doesn't work with your code... Maybe because I'm using `layoutSubviews`? Where should I add it?

Comment: In a `UIView` subclass (in `layoutSubviews()`). I've updated my question with the full code based on your answer, can you please help me found out what the problem is? Thanks!

Comment: Oh when I do it programmatically it works. But when I try to add it with a xib (`UIView` component with `qa` class in a `UIViewController` `xib` file) it doesn't. Any idea why?

Comment: I tried it works even with xib , I'll upload demo for you now

Comment: Thanks. Where would you upload it?

Comment: Thank you, be you didn't understand me correctly, I probably wasn't clear enough. Let me explain: I don't want to add a `xib` file of the `UIView` subclass. I have `xib` file of my `UIViewController` (called `MyVC1.xib` alongside with `MyVC1.swift`), on this `xib` file I add a `UIView` component and I set its type to the circleView. Do you understand what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Do you understand...?

Comment: see now I edited code.... , click middle button to load xib viewcontroller

Comment: Are you sure? I don't see any edit (the last one changes `300` to `100`)

Answer (score 0):

You have a fixed radius of 100, in a smaller frame the circle is being drawn out of the bounds of it. Change your radius to be flexible with the frame. I usually use something like

```
radius = min(canvasWidth/1.5, canvasHeight/1.5);
```

Comment: Do you mean `min(self.frame.width/1.5, self.frame.height/1.5)`? I've changed it from 100 and it still doesn't work

Comment: I've updated my question with the full code, can you please help me found out what the probelm is? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried a smaller radius hardcoded in with the smaller frame? The option might be how it is being added, I am honestly not that familiar with adding it as a subview, I usually subclass UIView and add it like that. It is possible that it cant create a smaller radius from the size because it doesnt know it yet.

Comment: What do you mean? What should I try?

Comment: If you are subclassing UIView, you dont need to physically add the views when you draw them, you just draw them. Call them from the draw function in the order you want them drawn. Then add a UIView to to your storyboard and give it this class as its custom class. This also ensures that the width and height your using are of the actual associated parent view.

Comment: Thank you. When I do it programmatically it works. But when I try to add it with a xib (UIView component with qa class in a UIViewController xib file) it doesn't. Any idea why?

Comment: No sorry, I havent dealt with Xibs yet. I still use the storyboard.

Comment: It's probably the same. Isn't it?